# When using spring MVC Model, when does the model instance is initialized and how?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, initialization

this is a sample example of controller

```
@Controller
public class AccountingController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/common/accounting")
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute(attributeName, attributeValue)
        return "/common/accounging/index";
    }
}
```

My question is, where does the model parameter in the index function is initialized?
How these values from this hash it translated to the request object?

Answer (score 0):

It's instantiated by Spring before calling the method, and every attribute of the model is then put in a request attribute (at least if JSP is usd as the view), so that the JSP EL can be used to access every attriubte directly.